# date_trunc PostgreSQL function equal for mySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Im trying to retrieve data to make statistics, im using mySQL and i cant get the following function to work - the postgreSQL is working.

I want to retrieve the request for the last month and count the amount of new requests for each day.

***postgreSQL***

```
SELECT count(*), date_trunc('day', created_at) as date FROM requests
WHERE(created_at > '2014-08-13 00:00:00') GROUP BY 2 ORDER BY 2 ASC;
```

***mySQL - my code ***

```
SELECT count(EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_at)), EXTRACT(DAY FROM created_at) as date
FROM `requests`
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY date
```

***Final code***

```
SELECT count( * ) , date( created_at ) AS date
FROM `requests`
WHERE DATE( created_at ) > DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) )
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent for your case is `date()`:

```
select date(created_at), count(*)
from requests
. . .
```

This isn't a general replacement, but it works to remove the time portion of a date.

EDIT:

Perhaps the better solution for these two databases is:

```
select cast(created_at as date)
```

This is ANSI standard and works in both these databases (as well as SQL Server).  I personally don't use this in general, lest I accidentally use it in Oracle, causing difficult to find errors.  (`date`s in Oracle have a time component, alas.)

Comment: `cast()` would make it even ansi compatible.

Comment: @pozs . . . `cast()` does work in MySQL, but it doesn't work in all databases. Notably, the Oracle `date` type includes a time component.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i wrote *ansi sql* compatible, not Oracle compatible. There is a difference :) (ansi sql explicitly mentions a cast from timestamp to date & date hasn't got time part in ansi)

Comment: @pozs . . . You made me wonder why I only use that formulation in SQL Server (where the alternative is really yucky).   But, that is a fine solution as well.